# Noether's Normalization Lemma of $k[x,y] /(xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R = k[x,y] / (xy)$. I want to find $x_{1} \in R$ such that $R$ is an integral extension of $k[x_{1}]$, where $k$ is some algebraically closed field.

I believe $d = 1$ as stated in noether's normalization lemma, but I could be wrong. I am having trouble finding such an element. Namely, if $x,y \in R$ are integral over $k[x_{1}]$, then I know I am done. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $x_1=x+y$ works.

Comment: $y^{2} - (x+y)y = x^{2} - (x+y) x = 0$. Right? So $x,y$ are integral